# Vb.net with access database: How can you help me simplify these codes?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

this is my code:

```
    'Set up connection string
    Dim cnString As String

    cnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=..\data\testingDB.mdb"

    Dim sqlQRY As String = "SELECT * " & _
        "FROM   users " & _
        "WHERE  firstName = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' " & _
        "  AND  lastName  = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"

    'Create connection
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cnString)

    Try
        ' Open connection
        conn.Open()

        'create data adapter
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQRY, conn)

        'create dataset
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet

        'fill dataset
        da.Fill(ds, "user")

        'get data table
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("user")

        'display data
        Dim row As DataRow

        If TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2) And dt.Rows(0).Item(5) = 10 Then
            MsgBox("10")
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2) And dt.Rows(0).Item(5) = 9 Then
            MsgBox("9")
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2) Then
            MsgBox("SUCCESS")
        Else
            MsgBox("fail")
        End If




    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString & vbCrLf)
    Finally
        ' Close connection
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

I'm trying it to make it simple with the same results. As you can see the if-else statements were messy but it works 100%. I do want the if-else statements to be simple and works the same as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to check value of row(5) for DbNull values
try this for if-else statements:

```
        Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows(0)
        Dim r5 as Object = row(5)
        If IsDbNull(r5) then r5 = 0

        If TextBox1.Text = row(1) And TextBox2.Text = row(2) Then
            Select Case r5
                Case 10, 9 : MsgBox(r5)
                Case Else : MsgBox("SUCCESS")
            End Select
        Else
            MsgBox("fail")
        End If
```

Comment: thank you sir! but will it work if the row(5) is empty? i always get an error if it's empty.

Comment: it works! one question, is this case statement is better than if-else(not in simplicity)?

Comment: additional, is it better to use case statements for inserting data than if-else?

Comment: @Lance `select case` and `if-else` statements can be used in code based on situation and what style you prefer. select-case can be sometimes better than if-else as you refer to a variable to be checked its value against other conditions (e.g. `r5` in above code). For your second question, i can not understand what you mean by: 'is it better to use case statements for inserting data than if-else?'

Comment: what I meant by inserting data is modifying, updating and adding new records in the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cmd as New OledbCommand
Dim sqlQRY As String = "SELECT  count(*) " & _
        "FROM   users " & _
        "WHERE  firstName = @fname " & _
        "  AND  lastName  = @lname"

cmd.parameters.add("@fname",TextBox1.Text)
cmd.parameters.add("@lname",TextBox2.Text)

Dim Cnt as Integer
cmd = new oledbcommand(sqlQRy,con)
Cnt = Convert.ToInt32( cmd.ExecuteScalar())
if  Cnt>=1 then
msgbox("Success")

else if 

msgbox("Failure")

end if
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, kind sir. But only the data adapter and data set/data reader/data table are the things that my mind can grasp at the moment. :D

Answer (score 0):

1. You must be aware that your SQL could logically return more than 1 row. You need to make sure that when you read data that you intend to test in this way, that your SQL uses a primary key and return 1 row only otherwise, problems could happen when more data is added. I suggest you first ensure that exactly 1 row is returned before you perform your if test (see my comment to @SenthilKumar). You need to send appropriate message to user when no rows are found and not perform the test.
2. If you get exactly 1 row back, you have to ensure that the data is not null (if applicable, this depends on how your columns are defined).
3. Remember that data that comes form UI could be padded with blanks or be in mixed case. You may need to watch for this.
4. Your IF statement is not too complex as is.I am not sure what you are testing exactly, but one can observe that you are using the following conditions:

TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2) And dt.Rows(0).Item(5) 
TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2) And dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)

You can see that the the expression
dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2) is common. You can assign the value to a Boolean expression and use it in your test.

You also should not include non-database processing in the scope of your try.

Comment: To elaborate my database the columns are the following:
ID>>firstname>>lastname>>username>>password>>progress>>score

my new problem now is: when the item(5) ,progress, is empty i always get an error, how to i fix this?

Comment: Enpty could mean zero characters or NULL value in DB. For DB Null, you could test using: If (IsDBNull(TempDT.Rows(0).Item(5)) = True) and you could test if a string is empty using If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(variable of type text)) Then... You should test for nulls first before further comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Just more little simpler ..

```
If TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1) And TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
    MsgBox("SUCCESS - " & format(dt.Rows(0).Item(5))) 
Else
    MsgBox("fail")
End If
```